# autoIt3 how to select n-th matched control?

Tags: autoit

When using autoIt to get Window's Text and the WinGetText matches multiple controls (e.g. with the same Class SciCalc in this case), the WinGetText will concatenate the text of all the controls. How can I get the Text of the n-th (say 3rd  'MR') control?

e.g.

```
Local $output = WinGetText("[CLASS:SciCalc]", "")

print 

output:666666.
MC
MR
MS
M+
7
4
1
0
8
5
2
+/-
9
6
3
.
/
*
-
+
=
Backspace
CE
C
1/x
sqt
%
```

Comment: I Just want to be sure, if there is three of the window you want to read from, you only want to read the text from the 3th window ?

Comment: The answer is NO. There are multiple controls in the same window. I want to find the nth-control in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
ControlGetText("[CLASS:SciCalc]","","[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:3]")
```

Use AutoIt Window Info to find the Advanced mode details on the wanted control.